# laravel eager loading returns part of data when passed through a collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have defined three relationships between a package which is the main entity has three relationships

. package hasmany "item 1" "item 2" "item 3"

when i fetch data using eager load am getting all items

but when i pass through the collection item 3 is lost

```php
public function all($pagination = 'm', $returnCollection = true)
{
    $data = $this->model->with('item1', 'item2', 'item3')->latest()->paginate(core_paginate($pagination));

    return $returnCollection ? $data : new PackageResourceCollection($data);
}
```

the collection

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        "data" => $this->collection,
        "headers" => (new Datatable)->headers($this->headers),
    ];
}
```

the relationships

```php
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item1::class, 'package_item1', 'package_id', 'item1_id')
        ->withPivot('price', 'discount', 'quantity', 'amount')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
    
public function item3()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item3::class, 'package_item3', 'package_id', 'item3_id')
        ->withPivot('price', 'discount', 'quantity', 'amount')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: Does item3 return null or it isn't there at all?